# Getting quests despite not being able to travel to the locations?

Tags: neverwinter

I'm a bit confused. I've gotten a quest (in this case culling the cultists) and would have to travel to the well of dragons in order to fullfill it.

Now the problem is: I'm lvl 39 and well of dragon only lets me travel there if I'm 70+.

Is that normal (thus are there many such questions which you can accept but not travel to) or am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 1):

The quests are meant for players that are later in the game. You can still take them but must progress further to complete them. Many games have quests/story lines that are introduced to the player early on but cannot be seen to their resolution for a while.